# Detect previous path in react router if i came from an outside application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react router. I want to detect the previous page (outside app example: coming from gmail to my application) from where I am coming from. I have the router in my context. But, I don't see any properties like "previous path" or history on the router object. How do I do it?

example 2: user places an order we send them an email confirmation via email where onclick on `view-order-details` they are navigated back to our web app, now how to detect which link they came from?

*Here's another context to understand better*

I have to implement a back button in my web app, when user comes from email to my webapp he's navigated to `https://example.com/orders/{orderID}` directly and if i just use `props.history.goBack` it'll go back to email page. But i want to user to be navigated to `https://example.com/dashboard`.

Now you might say use `props.history.push('/dashboard'`) this will become static value. if user is navigated internally(not coming from email or external page) from `dashboard->all-orders->orders/{orderID}` on click of back button should be navigated to `dashboard->all-order`s page and not to dashboard.

Comment: Usually you'd pass things like that in the query string of the link.

Comment: can you please explain what you meant? in this case how can i access the query string of the previous location?

Comment: Since you control the confirmation email, you can just add a query string in it which tells you where the link was sent, e.g. just add `&source=email` to the link which leads to *your* application, and then in *your application* you can read the current query string to figure out which link it was.

Comment: But perhaps I'm lacking some context - as it stands, the question seems like a bit of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What exactly are you attempting to do?

Comment: I have to implement a back button in my web app, when user comes from email to my webapp he's navigated to `https://example.com/orders/{orderID}` directly and if i just use history.goBack it'll go back to email page. But i want to user to be navigated to `https://example.com/dashboard`. Now you might say use history.push('/dashboard') this will become static value. if user is navigated from dashboard->all orders-> orders/{orderID} on click of back button should be navigated to dashboard->all orders page and not to dashboard.

Comment: i know its a long explanation, but i hope you figured out two different things i want to achieve here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214349/discussion-between-holla-mukunda-and-cbr).

Comment: You're looking to build back button, that if the user came from an external link (no referrrer) they should go back to the dashboard, but in case they came from an internal link the back button should actually go to the last visited page?
That use case is described in the documentation for referrer => `document.referrer` is an empty string when the page is not opened through a link.

Comment: So if referrer is not your own site or empty, go to dashboard. Otherwise use history.goBack()

Comment: Can  you please give me an example? i'm still no sure how to implement it @Mastacheata

Comment: Hello @holla I've added an example to my answer. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: It was helpful, i used your answer to formulate my logic  thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read the history in React-Router use the history object that's passed along with the routeComponentProps or the useHistory hook.

But that won't give you what you're looking for either:

1. There is no way to read entries in the browser history. Browsers simply don't expose that to JS at the moment. [See this entry on the history API on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history)
2. In order to detect which site a visitor came from you can check the referrer. [document.referrer on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)

Example for a button that goes back one step in history for internal referrers, but goes to the dashboard if the site was loaded from a bookmark or external link:

```js
button.onclick - () => {
  if (document.referrer && document.referrer.length > 0 && document.referrer.startsWith('https://yoursite.com')) {
    // user came from an internal link
    window.history.goBack(1);
  }
  else {
    // user came from a bookmark or an external link
    window.location = 'https://yoursite.com/dashboard';
  }
};
```

The HTML5 history allows you to go back to an arbitrary point in history, but you can't know the details about that point in history. You can only go back to it by a numerical index.

Comment: Thanks i went through the document, i hope there should be another method for this!

Comment: hey @holla could please share  your logic so others can get idea of it . Thanks